# Draw border around menu item

Tags: vb6

Is it possible to draw border around a menu item in vb6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean the menus at the top of the form, or popup-menus that appear when right-clicking.

- It's not possible in pure VB6.
- It *might* be possible with some complex API work to produce owner-draw menus. You could have a look at [this](http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/vb/code/controls/Menus/PopupMenu_-_OwnerDraw_Menu_Items/article.asp) or [this](http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=483)... bring your hatchet.

Answer (score 0):

Beyond what Mark has mentioned there is also the commercial [menu controls](http://www.codejock.com/products/commandbars/default.asp?platform=com) from CodeJock.  I am using them in a project and they are pretty fantastic.